# Вопрос о некорректной работе приложения, теоретической причине

Tags: java, android

Раньше думал, что код либо работает, либо нет. Но не тут то было)

Пишу приложение,типа магазина, на эмуляторе всё работает четко, сбоев никогда не бывает.
Когда тестирую на мобильном через wifi,то работает через 3-5-7 раз, как когда,у него своя атмосфера.
Когда тестирую на мобильном через мобильный интернет, то вообще не подгружаются нужные элементы.

Криво подгружается именно вот эта часть, где формируются разные `view` в зависимости от email и селектятся на сервере.

```
  StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, select_all, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {

            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("image_info_table");
                int sum=0;
                for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
                    JSONObject info = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    Item item=new Item();
                    item.setItem_name_Cart(info.getString("name"));
                    item.setImage(info.getString("path"));
                    item.setQuantity(info.getString("quantity"));
                    item.setPrice(info.getString("price"));
                    item.setSpinner_size(info.getString("size"));
                    array.add(item);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }

    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    }) {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
            parameters.put("email", email.getText().toString());
            return parameters;
        }
```

JSON ловит, но вот эта последующая передача и непонятная работа вводит меня в ступор. Может из-за того, что у меня Meizu на Flyme и что-то китайцы там намудровали, или какая-то перегруженная `mysql php` часть.

В чем может быть, чисто теоретическая причина, на эмуляторе же четко работает, может потому что ресурсы компьютера больше, или чего?

Comment: Отсутствуют проверки переменных на null при создании объектов. Такой код и не должен работать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чет код странный

```
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
        ...
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Я так понимаю что `adapter` отвечает за вывод `array` в `ListView`

И если перевести ваш код на русский, то звучит он так: распарсить JSON и если во время парса произойдет ошибка, то обновить `adapter`

Нужно вынести `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` из блока `catch`

```
try {
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
    ...
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Спасибо, именно тут был грех.

Answer (score 2):

Не буду вдаваться в тонкости кода ТС (коллеги на них уже указали). Скажу про другое: увлечение анонимными слушателями/классами до добра не доводит

Во всем должна быть своя мера, анонимный слушатель/класс/лямбда имеют четкий смысл когда тело коротенькое и простое - не вопрос.

Но как только тело класса или его сложность начинают превышать определенный предел - надо выносить как минимум во внутренний класс, а то и публичный внешний класс. Как результат:

1. Улучшается читаемость кода
2. Проще контролировать жизненный цикл объекта (поскольку его надо явно создавать) - следовательно, значительно сокращается возможность утечки

Где находится предел, когда надо отказываться от анонимного класса/лямбды? Честно не знаю. Грубо говоря, больше экрана: все, баста-карапузики - уходим на именованный класс, как то так.

Не пытался теоретически обосновать это положение (мне это не очень интересно) - строго практика, строго бессонные ночи наедине с отладчиком и свирепым заказчиком :)

Comment: Спасибо большое, я конечно понимаю что очень далек, пока что к лучшим традициям написания кода, ну будем к этому идти)